# Ramda JS filter out multiple values from an array at once based on two arguments

Tags: arrays, filter, arguments, ramda.js

Let's say I have an array of 7 values:
`[1.20, 0.50, 2.00, 0.75, 1.20, 0.75, 0.75]`

How can I strip out the 3 lowest values from this array using Ramda JS, so that it returns a new array:
`[1.20, 2.00, 1.20, 0.75]`?

Might as well need to strip out the 4 highest values from the array. That's why I'm talking about two arguments.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert the array to `[index, value]` pairs using `R.toPairs`, then sort it by the value (ascending or descending to the `sorter` function you pass), remove the last items according to `dropNum`, and then sort it back by the original order, and pluck the values:

```js
const { curry, pipe, toPairs, sortWith, descend, ascend, nth, dropLast, sortBy, pluck } = R

const fn = curry((dropNum, sorter, arr) => pipe(
  toPairs, // convert to [index, value] pairs
  sortWith([sorter(nth(1))]), // sort by the value ascending or descending
  dropLast(dropNum), // remove the last items
  sortBy(nth(0)), // sort by index to restore order
  pluck(1) // take the values
)(arr))

const arr = [1.20, 0.50, 2.00, 0.75, 1.20, 0.75, 0.75]

const remove3lowest = fn(3, descend)
const remove4higesht = fn(4, ascend)

console.log(remove3lowest(arr))
console.log(remove4higesht(arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```